# Spaces around Boolean argument to \IfValueT gives -NoValue-

Tags: xparse

This code compiles correctly as long as I don't put spaces around arguments `#3` and `#4` in the definition of `\vec`. I can't find anything about this in the `xparse` documentation, and I have been under the impression that spaces in such places are the preferred style in `LaTeX3` so I'd like to know why this happens. I have a feeling it may be trivial, but I'm not seeing it.

My MWE (contains code originally by @egreg):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{esvect}

% A smarter \vec command.
% Why doesn't it work when I put spaces around #3 or #4?
\RenewDocumentCommand{\vec}{ s m e{_^} }{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      {\vv{#2}}
      {\boldsymbol{#2}}
    _{\IfValueT{#3}{#3}\vphantom{\smash[b]{|}}}
    ^{\IfValueT{#4}{#4}\vphantom{\smash[t]{\big|}}}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\[
  \vec{E}_{\textup{ball}}
  \qquad
  \vec{E}_{_{\textup{ball}}}
\]
\[
  \vec{p}_{\textup{ball}}
  \qquad
  \vec{p}_{_{\textup{ball}}}
  \qquad
\]
\[
  \vec{F}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{\textup{proton}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}^{\textup{elec}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}^{\textup{elec}}_{\textup{proton}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{\textup{proton}}^{\textup{elec}}
\]
\[
  \vec{F}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{21}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{21}^{\textup{contact}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{\textup{table on ball}}^{\textup{contact}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}^{\textup{contact}}_{\textup{table on ball}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here is the result without the spaces in question:

[image: Output without spaces around #3 and #4]

And here is the result WITH the spaces in question:

[image: Output with spaces around #3 and #4]

Comment: If you want to use `\IfValueT{ #3 }{<true code>}`, then you need to surround definition of `\vec` in between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` pair. You can find the documentation of them in [manual of `expl3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ UPDATE: I just tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. I get an error that `\dn` isn't defined. I'll just do without the spaces for now.

Comment: Ah, the situation is a bit tricky. `\ExplSyntaxOn` changes the category code of `_`, hence the `_` used in definition of `\veb` in between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `...Off` now has catcode 11 (letter) while the `_` used in document has its normal catcode 8 (subscript). This makes `\vec` expecting a `_` (letter) but actually `_` (subscript) is met.

Comment: Unrelated: note that `\text` is the wrong command to use to make those -scripts upright. `\text` does not do what you think it does (it will be italic if the text outside math is italic, not what you wanted). In this case `\textup` is probably better. Sadly we see a lot of people misusing `\text` like this. You should only use it for textual comments in displayed math. This is not a comment but a textual sup-/superscript

Comment: Regarding italics: think theorems of definitions, these are normally in italics. It is just better overall to not promote a bad solution to others who comeby this question. A lot of people don't know it's bad

Comment: No matter what you choose as the replacement, `\text`  is the wrong choice here as it does not do what people expect. In some context textup is a good replacement some mention textnormal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(continue from [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554706/spaces-around-boolean-argument-to-ifvaluet-gives-novalue?noredirect=1#comment1400257_554706))

An ugly workaround:

- tokenize `e{^_}` before `\ExplSyntaxOn`, in order to frozen the catcode of `_`, and
- replace `_` (required) and `^` (just for consistent) by their command form `\sb` (su**b**-script) and `\sp` (su**p**er-script), respectively.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{esvect}

% A smarter \vec command.
% Why doesn't it work when I put spaces around #3 or #4?

\def\temp{ \RenewDocumentCommand{\vec}{ s m e{_^} } }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\temp{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      {\vv{#2}}
      {\boldsymbol{#2}}
    \sb{\IfValueT{ #3 }{#3}\vphantom{\smash[b]{|}}}
    \sp{\IfValueT{ #4 }{#4}\vphantom{\smash[t]{\big|}}}
  }%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  \vec{E}_{\textup{ball}}
  \qquad
  \vec{E}_{_{\textup{ball}}}
\]
\[
  \vec{p}_{\textup{ball}}
  \qquad
  \vec{p}_{_{\textup{ball}}}
  \qquad
\]
\[
  \vec{F}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{\textup{proton}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}^{\textup{elec}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}^{\textup{elec}}_{\textup{proton}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{\textup{proton}}^{\textup{elec}}
\]
\[
  \vec{F}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{21}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{21}^{\textup{contact}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}_{\textup{table on ball}}^{\textup{contact}}
  \qquad
  \vec{F}^{\textup{contact}}_{\textup{table on ball}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don’t need the `\expandafter`; category code are frozen once you define `\temp`

Comment: @egreg Thanks, you're right. Answer changed.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ You say this is an "ugly" workaround. What would be a more elegant one?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I'm afraid there is no simple (not much to patch) and elegant (without losing the readability) solution here.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Just to clarify, this workaround is just to use spaces around those two arguments. As long as I don't do that, there shouldn't be a problem, correct? I have changed `\text` to `\textup` and learned about `\sb` and `\sp` so it's been instructive.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Correct.