# Why can I not have space around an argument to \IfValueTF unless inside \ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff?

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse

This is similar to a previous question ([Spaces around Boolean argument to \IfValueT gives -NoValue-](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554706/218142)) but the answer to that one involved a math mode character and its catcode, whereas in this question there is no such issue.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\testing}{ o }
  {%
    \IfValueTF{ #1 }
    {#1}
    {false}
  }%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\testing
\end{document}
```

Without the `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` and without any spaces around `#1` in `\IfValueTF{#1}` I get the expected result (`false`). However, if I put spaces around the argument `\IfValueTF{ #1 }` I get `-NoValue-`, unless I also turn on `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff`. This can't be a mathmode issue or catcode issue like before, at least if it is I don't understand it. Also, if I make the argument to `\testing` mandatory rather than optional, this doesn't happen, but I still don't get `false` when I expect to. What is going on in this situation? I know `\NewDocumentCommand` doesn't require `xparse` but should I included it anyway and put all my definitions inside `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff`?

Comment: well outside \ExplSyntaxOn spaces matters.  \NewDocumentCommand requires xparse, but if you use the new latex-dev format, xparse is already included.

Comment: ExplSyntaxOn changes the catcode of space so it's ignored, but you are not using any expl3 code here so it is probably more correct to not use ExplSyntaxOn and not put spurious spaces around `#1` so it works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for telling me about the `latex-dev` format. I had seen that before but didn't know what it was.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wasn't aware space's catcode changes in `\ExplSyntaxOn' so that explains it.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL changing catcodes is all it does (more or less)

Comment: You might want to look at [What do ExplSyntaxOn and ExplSyntaxOff do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108696/82917).

Comment: @campa I have, and it presents a problem. Should document commands be consistently defined inside or outside ExplSyntaxOn...ExplSyntaxOff in preparation for the final LaTeX3 format? It make a big difference in certain cases and I see no consistency in practice. I'm thoroughly confused over what to do about it.

Comment: IMO it's the same as with `\makeatletter`: you use it if you need kernel macros. As long as you use only user-level commands no `expl` syntax is necessary. But again IMO, and I'm a lousy programmer.

Comment: If someone will make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `{ #1 }` and `{#1}` are *different*, unless the spaces get ignored during the tokenization phase.

With the standard category codes, `{ #1 }` is six tokens

`{`<sub>1</sub> <space><sub>10</sub> `#`<sub>6</sub> `1`<sub>12</sub> <space><sub>10</sub> `}`<sub>2</sub>

In particular, the spaces would be in the replacement text of the macro and the test `\IfValueTF{ #1 }` will always return true, because, in case the optional argument is missing, the passed argument is `<space>-NoValue-<space>`, which is different from `-NoValue-`

On the other hand, after `\ExplSyntaxOn` the category code of the space is set to 9 and such a character is discarded during the tokenization phase, unless it follows a character of category code 0 (the backslash), so in the `expl3` programming environment, the input `{ #1 }` is just four tokens

`{`<sub>1</sub> `#`<sub>6</sub> `1`<sub>12</sub> `}`<sub>2</sub>

In particular, after `\ExplSyntaxOn`, one can use “backslash-space” and get the usual token (that is a space in output). The problem of “backslash-space” at the end of a line is solved by setting `\endlinechar=32` (the space): TeX removes any trailing space from a line before starting tokenization, but in this case the space is reinserted as the endline character.

Answer (score 0):

As David Carlisle points out, the issue is one of catcodes and how they are affected by `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`.